# How to get value from a JSON array in PHP without knowing the node number?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm receiving the JSON array below with various permissions.
How to check the `publish_actions [status]` value if you don't know which node it is in? (currently it's in [3] but it could be any other number)

JSON array:

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [permission] => installed
            [status] => granted
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [permission] => public_profile
            [status] => granted
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [permission] => manage_pages
            [status] => granted
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [permission] => publish_actions
            [status] => granted
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [permission] => user_groups
            [status] => granted
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
  if($v['permission']=='publish_actions'){
    $newarr[]['permission'] = $v['permission'];
    $newarr[]['status'] = $v['status']
  }
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use json_decode and then iterate the array:

```
$publish_actions_status = '';
$array=json_decode($json_string);
foreach($array['data'] as $node){
    if($node['permission']=='publish_actions'){
        $publish_actions_status = $node['status'];
        break;
    }
}
```